# How to fix when i shorted 5v to gnd accidentally (Arduino Nano)

Tags: arduino-nano

I connected 5V to GND accidentally (connect directly, no LED, no motor). Now the LED on the board doesn't light up and power LED lights up but it is not bright. The 5V output pin is only around 1.98V. I'm using clone version from Alibaba. I ordered two, one is still working but the shorted one doesn't work. May I know how to fix them?

Comment: You very likely fried components on the board, and would have to troubleshoot and repair those components. If they are surface-mount components that is a highly skilled repai. As Systembolaget says, it's not likely worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that to repair an Arduino Nano clone yourself, if ICs/SMD parts are damaged, is not worth the effort, if you could do it at all (first having to find out which parts need to be replaced, carefully de-soldering the delicate SMD parts, then putting new parts in place, etc.).

Comment: First of all  thanks for answer my question, for my case MBR0520 diode is damaged, Voltage regulator is still working, i did a bypass from MBR0520 diode to voltage regulator and it's work perfectly.